# How to prevent form Submission on ClickFunnels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on ClickFunnels. I am working with AJAX by http Request method. I want to prevent form Submission on specific response value.

How can I achieve it ?

I had written below code yet to prevent form from submission

```
if(http.response == 'error')
{
    e.preventDefault();
}
else
{
    $('#abc').val("Thanks.");
}
```

If i wrote ***return false;*** instead of ***e.preventDefault();*** .... It is also not working.

Also on submission the function execute using below line

```
$("#submit-btn").click(function(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the previously "onSubmit" event handlers. see full example at [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZZdqKy?editors=1011).

```
function check (e) {
  $.get('https://api.github.com/', function(res) {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.hasOwnProperty('user_url')) {
      console.log('disabling the form.');
      $('#myform').removeAttr('onsubmit').submit( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("can't submit");
      });
    }
  })
}
```

btw, make sure your code runs at the right time. use "Event Listener" tab in chrome and lookup "submit" event. all submit handlers would be available there to stop, debug and investigate.

[image: event listener in google chrome]

Comment: you have to look for the "submit" handlers for **your specific** form and make sure your code runs **before** the submission process starts. "Event Listener" tab would help you track the behavior.

Comment: Kindly go through ClickFunnels form submission process then you can get know how about its form submission process. We can't handle it like this.